# Gazebo plugin camera feed inside gazebo simulation

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-model, gazebo-simulator

We are using interbotix wx200 arm . in that Gazebo simulation how do i import live video feed inside Gazebo environment. We are using intel real sense camera. I want whatever capturing that to be displayed  inside gazebo environment

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Manish T. I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking to do here, it sounds like you're wanting to use Gazebo for simulation. Are you asking how you can put live video into a simulation, or are you asking how you can create a video stream from a synthetic camera in Gazebo?